# Boost shared_ptr assert fails but the value is not NULL

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

in one of my applications I get an assert fail exception in the assert inside the boost shared_ptr dereference operator:

```
T * operator-> () const // never throws
{
    BOOST_ASSERT(px != 0); <------ fails!
    return px;
}
```

The problem is that using a debugger i see that the value of px is different from 0, something like 0x7ff.... ! Is such a situation possibile? How could the assert fail?

Thanks

Comment: Debuggers can lie to you - especially if building in release mode.

Comment: What kind of exception are you getting? If it's a memory access exception, then it's not due to the assert failing (which, btw, isn't compiled in in release mode).

Comment: Visual Studio often says 0xcdcdcdcd for a bad pointer.

Comment: Well, if the assert strikes, then your pointer **is** 0. The question is: why?  You should post how you construct your shared_ptr...something has to be wrong there

Comment: @Chris: He doesn't says the assert fails. He's saying that an exception is being thrown in the assert...

Comment: I'm using a debug build in Linux, the exception is the failed assertion. no other exception thrownis! The shared_ptr points to a boost asio socket object, created like this:
  
mysocket = boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>
   (new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io_service));

After that I always check the the pointer is valid:

if(mysocket.get() != NULL)

Comment: @Chris it was not perfectly clear in the explanation, but the title "assert fails" is pretty clear, edited the text too.

Comment: @cpl: Could the object be destroyed outside the `shared_ptr`? For instance by passing `mysocket.get()` to a function and calling `delete` on it?

Comment: No deletes at all, there's the smart ptr for that, it does not seem that the including object is deleted either!

Comment: @cpl: and no assignments to `mysockt`? Put a break-point on all member functions of `boost::shared_ptr` that modify `px`.

Comment: @DanielGehriger I will check that again. The strange thing is that I don't get an exeception, which could be triggered by a wrong reference do to another assignment, but a failed assert! I willl use a custom boost assert handler and see what i get...

Comment: @cpl? "Another thread?" - you are aware that `boost::shared_ptr` is not thread safe for write access? That is, reference counting isn't thread safe.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19427/discussion-between-cpl-and-daniel-gehriger)

Answer (score 1):

As you say yourself, the assert isn't failing. Instead, an exception is being raised inside it. This is not the same.

My guess is that the `boost::shared_ptr::px` member points to an incorrect memory location, and it does so, because the `boost::shared_ptr` object itself is invalid.

For instance, is your `boost::shared_ptr` used as a member of some class? If so, check if the object is valid (is `this` valid, has it's memory been corrupted)?

**Update:**

Ok - after your clarification that the assert is indeed failing: are you ever assigning to `mysocket` or even calling `mysocket.reset()`?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question to be more clear, but the assert actually fails, i get this in the console:


/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:414: T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.